# Determine buffer size for __i64toa_s

Tags: c++

I want to convert some numbers from `__int64` to `char`. For this purpose I want to use the function `__i64toa_s`, as suggested by MS. The function expects a char buffer for the return value. How can I determine the minimal needed size of this buffer? I don't want to get errors because of a too small buffer, but I don't want to waste space, too.
Thank you!

Comment: `(sizeof(__int64) * CHAR_BIT + (CHAR_BIT - 1)) / CHAR_BIT` should do the trick, I assume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply count, how many digits is in `__int64` value. By loop, or by `log10(value) + 1`, if `log10` is overloaded for `__int64`.

Comment: This seems a little wasteful to me. The function that is going to do the conversion will also count how many digits. There seems little point in doing to twice. If I were to use `__i64toa_s`, I'd use a fixed size buffer large enough to all values. Once `__i64toa_s` returns, I would know how many characters were needed, and I'd have all the characters, for onward processing.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you are right, fixed buffer should be fine here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming decimal output, you need a buffer of at least 21 characters. You need to allow for 19 digits for a 64 bit integer represented as decimal, a minus sign, and a null terminator.

However, since you are using C++, it would seem to me to make much more sense to use a C++ solution and avoid null-terminated C strings. I see no reason to use `__i64toa_s`. Use a string stream instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a more generic meta-function, which I use myself whenever I'm in need.

It calculates the maximum storage size for any numerical integral type in radix 10 by facilitating `std::numeric_limits<>`:

```c
/** @short Metafunction that calculates the maximum storage size for a string
 *  representation of a numerical type in base10, eventually including the sign.
 *
 *  @tparam T integral type, forwarded to std::numeric_limits<>
 *  @tparam null_inclusive whether to include the terminating null-character
 *  into the storage size
 */
template<typename T, bool null_inclusive = true>
struct digits10_storage_size:
  std::integral_constant<
    std::size_t,
    // note: digits10 returns the number of deciaml digits that the type can
    // represent without loss of precision, i.e. for char we get 2 digits (0..99)
    //
    // so we add here 1 to get 3 digits because [100..255] are 3 digits.
    // we add another time 1 because of an eventual sign (+/-) that a conversion
    // function could produce, plus finally the trailing \0-character eventually
    std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10 + 2 + null_inclusive
  >
{};
```

Advantages I see:

- compile-time solution
- fixed buffer that exactly fits the type instead of guessing, no matter the compiler/platform
- by using meta-programming techniques one could even generalize this meta-function for different radices

Usage:

```c
char szNum[digits10_storage_size<__int64>::value];
_i64toa_s(i, szNum, 10);
// ... or use "unsafe" version because of correctly precomputed buffer:
_i64toa(i, szNum, 10);
```